# Python: StandardScaler problem on text data in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I facing a problem while using the code snippet below

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('scale',StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(MLPClassifier(learning_rate = 'adaptive', solver = 'lbfgs',random_state=9000)))])
parameters = {'clf__estimator__alpha':[10.0 ** ~ np.arange(1, 7).any()],'clf__estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,),(50,)],'clf__max_iter': [1000,500],'clf__estimator__activation':('relu','tanh')}
grid = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, scoring= 'accuracy') 
with parallel_backend('threading'):
    grid.fit(X,Y)
```

In the above case `X = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(X_raw)` where `X_raw` is some texts stored in `pd.DataFrame`. And `Y` is `LabelEncoder.fit_transform(Y_raw)` where `Y_raw` is like `[['apple','lemon'],['orange','lemon'],['guava','watermelon'],........,['orange'],['orange','watermelon']]` . Please note apple, orange etc. shall never come in 2nd place within the list above.

The problem is the error

```
NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

I have earlier used this StandardScaler earlier it actually worked well when `Y_raw` is single value list i.e.`[['apple'],['orange']...]` . Is this due to `LabelEncoder`?  How to tackle this problem?

Comment: Anyone please? Do you think using OHE shall resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show the complete reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by taking out `StandardScaler.fit_transform(X)` outside of the `Pipeline`. Here `X` is already `TfIdfVectorizer.fit_transform` enabled. For `Y` I had used `LabelEncoder` only. Besides, `MLPClassifier` appears to be not an optimal one, therefore, I resorted to `SGDClassifier`. However, I am still wondering why it didn't work.